# How can I change the text box within a frame from the outer page in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a page with a button and a frame

In the frame I have another page with a text box

I want to be able to change the text by clicking the button

In other words I want the parent to change the son content...

Can you help?

Thanks
Asaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Text property is not visible from the parent, you must implement a public property or method on the child that will take care of changing the Text property.

```
class child
{

// this field cannot be accessed from a parent or anyone else
protected string Text="";

// This property can be used by a parent and other objects.
public string Message
{
get{ return Text; }
set{ if(value!=null) Text=value; } 
}

}
```

Comment: I thought I would get an answer with delegates... That I really need to learn...  But this answer was simple and effective. Thanks.